# Retrofit replacing signs on URL

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to make a request on retrofit 2, my url string is right, as I tested on Postman, but debugging my app I noticed that Retrofit is replacing the signs of my url and because of that it is returning an error on the request. Does someone knows how can I keep the signs in their places so the request can return success?

Example

I have the URL

[https://myapi.com/api/v1/name=João](https://myapi.com/api/v1/name=Jo%C3%A3o)

Retrofit is replacing this to

https://myapi.com/api/v1/name=Jo%C3%A3o

if it is only one sign I could make a method to replace all of occourences of it, but I need to consider all the signs available, so it will be unviable to make a method to it. I need a better and smarter solution. Thank you

Comment: are you passing the complete url or using query?

Comment: I'm passing the complete URL with the @Url annotation